# Search for each keyword entered in the textare based on new line

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build search functionality where user can submit multiple keywords each one on new line in the textarea and then perform search in database table.

The problem is with my current code that I have is searching for the last keyword only.

Here is the function that I have in my controller. I'm not sure if the query should be in the foreach loop at all.

```
    public function search(Request $request){

        $search = $request->input('search');

        foreach(explode("\r\n", $search) as $line) {
            $result = Posts::query()
            ->where('title', 'LIKE', "{$line}%")
            ->get();
        }
        return view('search', compact('result'));        
    }
```

Here is the textarea on the search blade

```
    <form role="form" id="form-buscar" action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">
        <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="search"  rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Search..." required></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: `$reuslt` (watch out for a typo here) will be overwritten on each iteration. Last one wins

Comment: you're overriding the ``$reuslt`` everytime. Instead of `` $reuslt = `` change to `` $reuslt[] = ``

Comment: because you are always assigning the `$reuslt` variable which will be overwritten each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contain like condition with foreach function instead all the query:

```php
$search = $request->input('search');
$query = Posts::query();
foreach (explode("\r\n", $search) as $line) {
    $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "{$line}%");
}
$result = $query->get();
return view('search', compact('result'));
```

Comment: Thanks but no results now. Not even the last one.

Comment: @Jake Have you tried `->orWhere` instead of `->where`?

Comment: Can you try orWhere ?

Comment: Yes, with `->orWhere` return only last word

Comment: Okay, tested it again and it works with `->orWhere`. I removed `\r\` for tests and it doesn't work without it but when I put it back it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: check other conditions. Maybe it is related with timestamps or show query logs with this

Comment: DB::enableQueryLog();

// and then you can get query log

dd(DB::getQueryLog());

Comment: You too dear. Good lucks !